# Power Operation With Floats in Transaction SQL

Tags: t-sql

I am fairly new to using T-SQL, and I am having issues with the POWER operation. Whenever I attempt to write a query with a line such as the following:

```
POWER(table1.TotalIndexValue / table2.TotalIndexValue, 0.33333) - 1
```

I get an error message saying:

> An invalid floating point operation occurred

whenever the second argument is an integer, I do not get this error message. I also attempted changing 0.33333 to (1/3), but that did not work either.

How do you raise something to a non-integer power?

Comment: I don't think [**POWER**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx) allows you to use a non-integer parameter as the power to raise your number to. Try looking up the math of raising a number to a non-integer power, based on root (square root, cubic root etc.) and logarithms. Can't remember the exact math right now..

Comment: its not just the second argument causing your issue.. it's a combination of the first argument and second.  This works `SELECT POWER(2.0 / 3.0, 0.33333)`  this fails `SELECT POWER(-2.0 / 3.0, 0.33333)` you'll need to figure out how to make the first argument a non negative number

Comment: The issue ended up being with negative numbers.I made an underlying assumption about the dataset that turned out to be untrue in a couple of corner cases.